# Detecting special chars in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have usernames in my postgres 9 db such as

```
Ron R ty ♥☆♡★Green Eyes♥☆♡★
Sωℯℯт۞Angel 2 ᾧ➍ᾧ ty Լù☪ƖƒεƦ
```

the db is encoded in utf-8

is there a way to detect the presence of these special chars outside standard roman chars in SQL?

I tried using `convert` documented here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html but only got errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try matching on a regexp character range based on unicode code-point.

```
WHERE uname ~ '[\x80-\xffff]';
```

Or, if you want to be more strict you can exclude anything non-alphanumeric.

```
WHERE uname ~ '[^[:alnum:]]
```

Other character-classes are available too. See [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) for details.

Comment: Sorry for tardy response.